# Structural Equation Model design through AMOS, interpretation help

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, amos

I have calculate the estimates through Maximum Likelihood procedure with model of six latent variables(presented in big ellipse) with respective observed variables (presented in rectangle) in AMOS 20.0. The relationship between latent and observed variable represent factor loadings which should be greater than 0.5 in my case. Now issue is perceived playfulness two factor loadings are problematic. One is negative (PP_2: -0.14) and other one is too low (PP_1: 0.20). What is the reason for these abnormal factor loadings. If i remove these two factor loadings problem still remains my PP_4 gets negative. I don't have justification grounds in terms of reference paper or supportive evidence?
From the diagram below, a clear illustration of my problem is available.
A better explanation would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Note:
Three factor loadings are compulsory with a latent variable. In this case, I cannot reduce pp_4 or PP_5 or PP_3

Comment: What happens if you just fit that variable on its own, in a small model. (Also, three loadings aren't 'compulsory', but they're usually useful).

Comment: What's your model fit like? What's your sample size?

Comment: The sample size is 158 and i didn't tried it for small model.

Comment: That's a huge and complex model for a pretty small sample size. Failure in any part of the model will lead to an overall failure, which will be very hard to diagnose - problems tend to 'flow' through a model - a problem in one place pops up as a problem in a different place (I've heard it described as statistical 'whack-a-mole'. First, test your seven individual factor models. Then test a CFA in which all the latent variables are correlated. If those all work, move on to the big model.

Comment: But if this were my dataset, I'd create composite scores for each of the scales, and then treat the scales as measured variables. (And that's still a decent sized model for this sample).

Comment: Well, at this point i can't undo or modify it in terms of changing variables.What should i do ?

Comment: Fit the single factor models. If they don't fit, and you can't change (or drop) variables, then you accept that your model doesn't work and the theory is wrong.  (That sounds harsh, but I'm not sure I understand why you can't change variables).

Comment: If my counts are correct, you have 528 covariances going into your model, and a 186 people. It's usually recommended that the sample size is at least a couple of times larger than the number of covariances.